# Magento: Display attribute name and value on category page

Tags: php, magento, entity-attribute-value

I'm trying to display both a product attribute value and the attribute label (attribute label="Available Colours" attribute code='available_colours') on the category page for a specific attribute set (id=9).

I am currently using the following code to display the attribute value, but cant seem to get the attribute label to display as well.

```
<?php 
    if (9 == $_product->getAttributeSetId()) {
        echo $_product->getAvailableColours() 
    } 
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Following should help:

```
    <?php 
        $attributeSetId = 9;
        if ($attributeSetId == $_product->getAttributeSetId()) {
            echo $this->__('Available Colours') . "=" . $_product->getAvailableColours(); 
        } 
    ?>
```

if you want to print for multiple attributes you can try below code:

```
    <?php 
$attributeSetId = 9;
    if ($attributeSetId == $_product->getAttributeSetId()) {
          $productData = $_product->getData();

          foreach($productData as $attributeCode=>$attributeValue) {
               echo $attributeCode . "=" . $attributeValue; //You can do needed customization to check if attribute value is array then there will be a second loop here.
            }
    } 
    ?>
```

Also, its best not to use static id as it may change with servers.

With following code you will be able to load attribute set id dynamically from attribute set name

```
<?php

$attributeSetName = "default"; // put your own attribute set name $attribute_set = 

Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set")->getCollection(); 

$attribute_set->addFieldToFilter("attribute_set_name",$attributeSetName)->getFirstItem(); 

$attributeSetId = $attribute_set->getAttributeSetId(); //In your case you will get 9

?>
```